# How to end the conversation and stop talking in AWS Lex? I want to delegate the conversation to a human

Tags: chatbot, aws-lex

I have a chat bot developed using AWS Lex with a Facebook Messenger integration. However, while I want the chat bot to handle the initial conversation, a human should be able to pick up the conversation if the chat bot fails.

Is it possible to "turn off" the chatbot in this scenario, so that once the chat bot has delegated the conversation to a human, it no longer tries to respond to the user?